# Get "Set-Cookie", "Location" Header Fields with AFNetworking 2.3.1 for iOS

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I send a post request with password and login data to the server. 
I need verify that username and password is correct.
With curl I check 2 Fields in Header: "Set-Cookie" and "Location".

**Response with correct login data:**

> Vitaliys-MacBook:~ aivs$ curl -d "act=login&login=19276&pass=abcdif" https_my_server/zboxweb --header "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --dump-header /dev/stdout
>   HTTP/1.1 302 Found
>   Server: nginx
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Expires: 01 Dec 1980 00:00:00 +0400
>   Set-Cookie: ZBW_SESSID=34523cf45445e0072f0555692cdea2a9e3fdd308; path=/; expires=Wed, 23-Jul-2014 10:32:53 GMT
>   Date: Wed, 23 Jul 2014 10:17:53 GMT
>   Location: https_my_server:443/
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS

**Response with incorrect login data:**

> Vitaliys-MacBook:~ aivs$ curl -d "act=login&login=10286&pass=1234567" https_my_server/zboxweb --header "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --dump-header /dev/stdout
>   HTTP/1.1 302 Found
>   Server: nginx
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Expires: 01 Dec 1980 00:00:00 +0400
>   Set-Cookie: ZBW_SESSID=; path=/; expires=Wed, 23-Jul-2014 10:18:19 GMT
>   Date: Wed, 23 Jul 2014 10:18:19 GMT
>   Location: https_my_server:443/zboxweb?err=bad_login
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS

With "Set-Cookie" and "Location" fields I can see that the login data is correct or incorrect

AFNetworking 2.3.1 doesn't show these fields!

```c
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES; // not recommended for production
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
[manager POST:@"https://find.zwave.me/zboxweb/"
   parameters:@{@"act": @"login", @"login": @"19276", @"pass" : @"abcdif "}
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
          NSLog(@"Header: %@",operation.response.allHeaderFields);
      } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
      }];
```

**AFNetworking Response with incorrect login data:**

```
2014-07-23 15:14:23.911 Z-Way Tablet APIv1[22666:60b] Header: {  
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" = true;  
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "GET, POST, OPTIONS";  
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";  
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";  
Connection = "keep-alive";  
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;  
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";  
Date = "Wed, 23 Jul 2014 11:12:13 GMT";  
Expires = "Wed, 23 Jul 2014 11:12:13 GMT";  
Server = nginx;  
"Set-Cookie" = "ZBW_SESSID=; path=/; expires=Wed, 23-Jul-2014 11:12:13 GMT";  
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;  
}
```

In response with incorrect login data "Set-Cookie" field is exist

**AFNetworking Response with correct login data:**

```
2014-07-23 15:57:00.268 Z-Way Tablet APIv1[22738:60b] Header: {  
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" = true;  
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "GET, POST, OPTIONS";  
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";  
Connection = "keep-alive";  
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;  
"Content-Type" = "text/html";  
Date = "Tue, 22 Jul 2014 09:21:21 GMT";  
Etag = "\"53a152fb.4288\"";  
"Last-Modified" = "Wed, 18 Jun 2014 08:51:07 GMT";  
Server = nginx;  
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;  
}
```

In response with correct login data "Set-Cookie" and "Location" fields isn't exist

How to use AFNetworking 2 to get "Set-Cookie" and "Location" fields?

Comment: By `Location: https_my_server:443/zboxweb?err=bad_login` did you mean  `Location: https*://*my_server:443/zboxweb?err=bad_login` ?